# expected output is not coming in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am trying to scrap the mega menu from the website using python beautiful soup frame work !

```
for i in menu_items('https://natureshair.com.au/'):
   print(json.dumps(i, indent=6))
```

The output is fine! I can able to different level of menus !

[image: output]

Now i want to see the result in browser so i have used  Django framework to display this out put in browser

this is my views.py code

```
def say_hello(request): 
    for i in menu_items('https://natureshair.com.au/'):
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps(i, indent=6))
```

But i am getting only first level of menu list in browser ! dont know where i have missed something

[image: browser outout]

Please let me know what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enumerate over the results, but you *return* a response from the moment you get the first item. This thus means that it returns the result from *that* item.

You thus should first collect all results, and then dump that blob:

```
def say_hello(request):
    results = list(menu_items('https://natureshair.com.au/'))
    return JsonResponse({'results': results})
```

or for two websites:

```
def say_hello(request):
    results = list(
        item
        for link in ('https://natureshair.com.au/', 'https://www.google.com/')
        for item in menu_items(link)
    )
    return JsonResponse({'results': results})
```

Comment: perfect ! can i add 2 website here ?

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonResponse instead of HttpResponse

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def say_hello(request): 
    for i in menu_items('https://natureshair.com.au/'):
        return JsonResponse(i)
```

Comment: getting error : C:\Users\mustb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request)

Comment: Then menu_items is None or empty list